# Questions when building bar charts by D3.js

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

Freshboy got several questions when creating my first bar chart by D3.js:

1. line 30 -- `console.log(yScale);` The console shows "function.....", what's this? ; Last line-- Why I can get correct answers of each column whenI give
   *"height"* the value *"yScale"*. What's happening there?
2. `.attr("x", function(data, i){return xScale(i)})` *xScale* is a variable not a function. Why can I use *xScale* like a function--*`xScale(i)`*?

```js
var data = [4,8,15,16,23,42];

const svg = d3.select("svg");

const margin = {top:25, right:25, bottom:25, left:25};

const xDomain = [0,5];
const xRange = [0,200];
const yDomain = [0,42];
const yRange = [0,200];
const rectWidth = 200 / 6;

const xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain(xDomain)
    .range(xRange);
var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain(yDomain)
    .range(yRange);

const g = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(50,50)");

createRect = g.selectAll("rect")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("x", function(data, i){return xScale(i)})
    .attr("y", function(data,i){
        console.log(yScale(data));
        console.log(yScale);
        return 200-yScale(data)})
    .attr("width", rectWidth)
    .attr("height", yScale);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src='https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js'></script>
<style> rect {fill: lightblue; stroke: black; }</style>
<body>
<svg width=300 height=300>
</svg>
<script src="w8-1-4 Axes.js">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Both xScale and yScale are functions.**

This is what you see when you log yScale and why you can use xScale "like a function". `d3.scaleLinear()` returns a function to scale values. In javascript, functions are objects, object properties can also be functions (methods in this case to set values such as domain and range).

Most simply:
`d3.scaleLinear()` returns a function.

With d3 scales (and most d3 functions), you create a new scale function with d3.scaleLinear() and then use the scale's methods to set values such as the scale's domain or range. The method returns the scale itself, hence why you can chain together several methods, modifying the scale function as you go.

**Why don't you need to pass any parameters to yScale when using `.attr("height",yScale)`?**

D3 uses [Function.prototype.apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) to pass paramaeters to any function provided to .attr() (or many other methods in D3, such as `selection.style()` or `selection.each()`). By using .apply D3 "calls a function with a given this value, and arguments provided as an array". The `this` value in D3 is generally an individual element, the first parameter, canonnically `d`, is the datum associated with that element, the 2nd paremeter, cannonically `i`, is the index of that element, and the last parameter is the group of elements in the selection.

The function passed to .attr() is called for each element in the selection.

The scale function takes one parameter, a value to be scaled. As your datum is a number, we can pass the scale function directly to .attr(): the first parameter passed to it will be the datum.

Carrying forward the above and for reference,

```
.attr("height",xScale)
```

produces the same result as:

```
.attr("height", function(d) {
    return xScale(d);
 })
```

as `d` is an element's datum (an item from the data array), we can use either approach above.